# Can't Xor Inline ASM in Lazarus Pascal - Access Error

Tags: asmx, pascal, lazarus

I need to xor the words in a file to calculate a checksum. I took some uncommented online code and changed the add to xor (with minimal other changes). How do I get the xor to work?

See line marked with '*** Change to xor'. I thought changing 'add' to 'xor' should work.

Code was attached to a form with a single button. I added a WriteDemoFile procedure to try to make this example self contained but it also has a problem.

Thanks to lurker I persisted a bit more and I can see that it is not just that add/xor line.  I mostly get an 'Access violation.' error when I disable WriteDemofile and use ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetCheckSum('c:\Autoexec.bat')));. If it compiles it returns a MessageBox with 25964 - the same result with add or xor. By the third run if it compiles the Access violation error occurs again. I suppose it is a memory addressing problem. How do the asm variables get loaded? What is happening with 'xor eax, [edi + 2*ecx]'?

```pascal
unit Unit1;
// Free Pascal Lazarus Version#: 1.2.6
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$asmmode intel}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

  procedure WriteDemoFile;
  function GetCheckSum(FileName: string): WORD;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure WriteDemoFile;

var
  Buffer: array[0..85] of byte = (
  $01, $00, $00, $00, $01, $00, $00, $00, $74, $65, $73, $74, $00, $00, $00, $00,
  $00, $74, $78, $74, $00, $00, $00, $00, $40, $00, $00, $00, $0B, $00, $00, $00,
  $34, $11, $4D, $41, $47, $45, $4C, $4C, $41, $4E, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
  $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
  $48, $65, $6C, $6C, $6F, $20, $57, $6F, $72, $6C, $64, $4D, $41, $47, $45, $4C,
  $4C, $41, $4E, $00, $0B, $2B
  );
  FileStream1: TFileStream;

begin
  with FileStream1.Create('TestArchive.Imi', fmCreate) do
  try
    FileStream1.Write(Buffer[0], SizeOf(Buffer)-1);
  finally
    FileStream1.Free;
  end;
end;



function GetCheckSum(FileName: string): WORD;
// http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=324
var
  F: file of WORD;
  P: Pointer;
  Fsize: WORD;
  Buffer: array [0..500] of WORD;
begin
  FileMode := 0;                        // Read only
  AssignFile(F, FileName);              // Use FileName variable
  Reset(F);                             // Open file (read only)
  Seek(F, FileSize(F) div 2);           // Calculate numer of words
  Fsize := FileSize(F) - 1 - FilePos(F);// Calculate fsize from current position
  if Fsize > 500 then Fsize := 500;     // Limit fsize to 500
  BlockRead(F, Buffer, Fsize);          // Read file into buffer fsize length
  Close(F);                             // Close file
  P := @Buffer;                         // Pointer to address of buffer
  asm
     xor eax, eax                // initialise eax as nul for checksum variable
     xor ecx, ecx                // initialise ecx as nul for position variable
     mov edi , p                 // move ptr to edi
     @again:                     // start of again routine
       add eax, [edi + 2*ecx]    // add 2bytes at new position *** Change to xor
       inc ecx                   // next record (2 bytes)
       cmp ecx, fsize            // compare position variable with file size
     jl @again                   // if previous calculation is less jump to again
     mov @result, eax            // move eax variable to result address
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WriteDemoFile;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(GetCheckSum('TestArchive.Imi')));
end;

end.
```

Comment: Clarification: 2 byte word needs to be xor'd with 2 byte word.

Comment: What do you mean, *...get the `xor` to work?* What about it isn't working?

Comment: I wasn't making any assumption about whether the code worked or not, having no basis to judge it that way. You had just said in your problem statement that you can't get `xor` to work, but didn't offer any clues about what that meant. So what you're saying is that you're getting results that don't make sense and occasional access violations? You should add some of those specifics to the question by editing it so that the information is easier to read.

Comment: For typed files (`file of...`), `FileSize`, `FilePos` return the number of records, not bytes.

Comment: FilePos would be 0 in this example so that wouldn't affect it. Makes me question if this code ever really worked though.

Comment: FilePos would be zero, but FileSize would be the number of words (not bytes) in the file.

Comment: Do you mean that the seek line is OK but the line under it is wrong?

Comment: The Seek line is wrong - FileSize is divided by two but the value is already the word count.